# Text Classification Using Ernie - How to view the predicted values

Tags: python, classification

Working on text classification project and using Ernie. I could able to prediction with the test data (~4000 observations) but the output is showing like this

I am unable to view the predicted values.

"df_test" is my test dataframe.

"df_test_new_ls" - converted the text column to a list and passing it prediction

prob = classifier.predict(df_test_new_ls)

Now, the "prob" is the generator which has the predicted values. how to get those values?